# iPhone - Instruments ObjectAlloc GeneralBlock

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, malloc

Okay, I have been trying to days to lower the Net Bytes on GeneralBlock 16,  I understand that a GeneralBlock is created by the iPhone's OS when creating its own object.  Is it possible to lower this alloced memory?  I have read in some places that GeneralBlock is something that you shouldn't worry about. True?

Answer (score 0):

This topic [Leak - GeneralBlock-3584](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478242/leak-generalblock-3584) answers to your question.

> You have nothing to worry about, this is false positive from Instruments. 
>   It has to do with freeing resources of the thread that has being terminated. They are just laying around until next thread is done and cleans resources after the one of the previously terminated. Instruments take this for a 'leak' but it's the feature of pthreads implementation on the iPhone OS which in perfect world would be handled differently. More on this on the Apple's dev forum